# How to automatically log 8 hours on jira every day?

Tags: jira

Plain and simple: I need jira to automatically log 8 hours with a predefined description always on the same task, once a day, every working day.
If I need to modify it, then I will do it by myself manually.

The expected result is that I don't have to log on jira everyday to log 8 hours, or log at beginning of the month and fill all 20 working days with 8 hours.

The date to date autofill is not enabled on our jira.

Comment: Working around stupid administrative requirements is an antipattern. Sigh. Sincere condolences to you.

Comment: I truly understand your pain (been there too many times) but the best you can get is a workaround, not a solution :-(

Comment: Well, seems I have to do some scripting. Leeeet's code